# Azure Disk Data Lost

Tags: azure, data-loss

I am new to Azure. I have created a VM. and stored some very important files on temp storage, but after few days the temp disk is formatted. is there any option I can get my data back ??

Comment: if they were very important, then why store them in temporary storage in the first place?

Comment: Actually there was an issue with xampp in other drive that's why i had to keep wamp setup temporarily in temp disk. Is there any solution you can tell ??

Comment: pray you had a backup in another location, I'm afraid.  Microsoft won't restore a temporary disk, to my knowledge at least.

Comment: Short answer: No. Think of the temporary disks as the local hard drive storage on the physical server in the data center. They aren't backed up and there are not (nor have there ever been) reliability guarantees around data stored on those temporary disks. If the hard drive in the data center dies, all data on the temporary disk is lost. Permanent disks utilize Storage instead in order to provide those reliability guarantees.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eshant 
               Just wanted to provide you with clear guidance regarding the disks and why you lost data. There are 3 Disks with in Azure VM, the are as follows

**C Drive**  127 GB Dedicated for OS will persist after reboot. This disk is dedicated for OS and shouldn't be used for any other purpose.

**D Drive** is  Temporary Drive is only intended for storing temporary data. As you notice it only has  page file on it and is not recommended for storing data because it is wiped clean on Stop and start, resize of VM , un/planned maintenance, and service healing. One key benefit  of this disk is performance. I/O performance for temporary disks is higher than the IO permanence to OS disks, Data Disks. The size of the disk varies with VM Size. *In your case the data is lost and cannot be recovered.*

**Data Disk.**  You need to add  Data disks for any type of custom storage that needs to be persisted. Another point being ,the difference between OS and data disks is that, while both reside in blob storage, the host caching settings are different by default - OS disk is Read/Write host caching by default, data disks are None host caching by default.

One key point is , the C:\ and D:\ cost is included in the VM Price , Data disk will be charged on actual usage. Say if you allocate 100 GB and use only 10 GB. Then you be charged only for the 10 GB.

Regards
Krishna

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to recover your data.

From this Microsoft article: **Understanding the temporary drive on Windows Azure Virtual Machines**
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wats/archive/2013/12/07/understanding-the-temporary-drive-on-windows-azure-virtual-machines.aspx

> **Is there a way to recover data from the temporary drive?**
>
> There is no way to recover any data from the temporary drive.